# Is the following Saheeh?

Tags: hadith

I have come across the following hadith

“Allah does not accept the fard and nafl ‘ibadah of three people; One disobedient to his parents, one who reminds others of his favours and one who rejects taqdir”

I want to know if this is an authentic hadith and whether some graded it weak or not.